Read and write XML with namespace set as it is
I create XML in my app.
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;


public class MyTest 
{
    void foo () throws Exception
    {
        String xml = "";
        xml += "<env:root xmlns:env=\"http://env\" xmlns:test=\"http://test\">";
        xml +=   "<env:sub xmlns:test=\"http://test\">";
        xml +=     "<test:val>123</test:val>";
        xml +=   "</env:sub>";
        xml += "</env:root>";
        
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream (xml.getBytes());
            
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance ();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder ();
        Document doc = db.parse (bais);
        
        // change nothing of the XML structure

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance ();
        javax.xml.transform.Transformer tr = tf.newTransformer ();
        tr.setOutputProperty (OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter ();
        tr.transform (new DOMSource (doc), new StreamResult (sw));
        
        System.out.println (sw.toString());
        
    }
}

The output is a little different than the input. Double namespace-declarations are removed.
Output is
<env:root xmlns:env="http://env" xmlns:test="http://test"><env:sub><test:val>123</test:val></env:sub></env:root>

Declaration of namespace test in sub is removed.
That is valid as far I know.
But now the system that reads the content has a problem with it.
Is there a way I can have the namespaces as they are set?? I had a look at the properties but did not found anything.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34923852/parsing-a-xml-not-keeping-duplicated-namespaces-in-the-parent-node-and-child-nod
